# FileUpload.HasFile always remain false(I am using Ajax)

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am writing one simple page in APS.Net with VB.Net as the scripting language. In this page I have two text boxes and relevant buttons to complete the job of taking input from the user.

The form prompts the user to enter an image title, image to upload(using ASP AjaxControlToolkit FileUpload control) and a list of search tags to research this image in the future.

I have researched for more than three hours and tried many different solutions posted online but still I am not able to fix the FileUpload.HasFile = False problem. This condition always remains false even after choosing the file to upload.

I understand that many similar questions have already been posted but I have tried those solutions and still I could not fix it.

It would be really great if someone could please help me with this.

I am using MS SQL database but I haven't done anything related to database in this page as I am not done with the validation and the input yet.

Please download the code files from:

http://www.mediafire.com/?ae1jq33zkj50tt7,olcmd5yct3tz52m,7lm3a9syplfdec6

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/fileupload-control-in-update-panel-using-Asp-Net-ajax/ Checkout this , you may get some help from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What u need is here!](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/fileupload-control-in-update-panel-using-Asp-Net-ajax/) Checkout this , you may get some help from here.

mark this as answer if u like it. :)

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem. I can't vote up because I am new. I will when possible.